# Ruby References

Tags: ruby, reference

When I have the following method:

```
def n_times(thing)
  lambda { |n| thing * n }
end
```

and I call it like that:

```
x  = [:a]
p1 = n_times(x)
x  = [:b]
p p1.call(3) # => [:a, :a, :a]
```

x will not be changed, the output will be [:a]. Why?

When doing something like .pop instead, x will be changed:

```
x  = [:a]
p1 = n_times(x)
x.pop
p p1.call(3) # => []
```

Is it because [:b] is a new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `x` was assigned a new object in first case. You can check by inspecting the `object_id`

```
x  = [:a]
p x.object_id # =>  //some number
p1 = n_times(x)
x  = [:b]  
p x.object_id  # => //diff number
p p1.call(3) # => [:a, :a, :a] 

x  = [:a]
p x.object_id # =>  //some number
p1 = n_times(x)
x.pop
p x.object_id # => //same number
p p1.call(3) # => []

# Another example
x  = [:a]
p x.object_id # =>  //some number
p1 = n_times(x)
x[0]  = :b 
p x.object_id # => //same number
p p1.call(3) # => [:b, :b, :b]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because [:b] is a new object?

Yes. When you do `x.pop`, you're modifying the object that both `x` and `thing` refer to. When you do `x = [:b]`, you make `x` refer to a new object. Making a variable refer to a new object doesn't affect other variables or objects.

Note that if the lambda closed over the variable `x`, it would be a different matter. In that case changing `x` would affect the lambda, but that's not the case. The lambda closes over the variable `thing`, which is a different variable that only happened to refer to the same object until `x` was reassigned.